# definite integral question?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

What's the definite integral:
$$\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{(2x+1)^3} dx$$

I get the answer $\;\;-\dfrac{1}{2(2x+1)^4}$

When I solve I get $(1/162) - (1/2) = -40/81$ , which gives me a negative answer.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: This is not a primitive.

Comment: Evaluating $I=\int (2x+1)^{-3} dx$ should give you something in terms of $(2x+1)^{-2} $, not $(2x+1)^{-4}$. You seem to have differentiated instead of integrated.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps guy. but i dont understand how u guys change from x=0 to x=1, to x=1 to x=3

Comment: What's this property or formula comes from ? I don't think I've learned this from my teacher yet. Could you guys show me a website link regarding to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $u = 2x + 1$. Then $du = 2\,dx \implies \,dx = \dfrac 12 \,du$

Your bounds of integration then change: when $x = 0, u = 1$, and when $x = 1, u = 3$.

$$\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{(2x+1)^3} dx = \frac 12 \int_1^3 u^{-3} \,du$$

$$ \frac 12 \int_1^3 u^{-3} \,du = \frac12\cdot -\frac{1}{2} u^{-2}\Big|_1^3 = \dfrac{-1}{4u^2}\Big|_1^3 = -\frac 14 \left(\frac{1}{9} - 1\right) = \frac 29$$

Comment: Thanks for all the helps guy. but i dont understand how u guys change from x=0 to x=1, to x=1 to x=3

Comment: Is this clear why we need to change the bound of integration? Since we are substituting $u = 2x + 1,$ we need to find the value of $u$ when $x = 0$ (lower bound), and the value of $u$ when $x = 1$.}  When $x = 0 \implies u = 2\cdot 0 + 1 = 1$. $x = 1 \implies u = 2\cdot 1 + 1 = 3.$  Since we are substituting to integrate in terms of $u$, we need to use matching parameters for integration

Comment: What's this property or formula comes from ? I don't think I've learned this from my teacher yet. Could you guys show me a website link regarding to this ?

Comment: It comes from the fact that we are substituting $u = 2x + 1$: we use this equation to find the value of $u$ at x = 0, and to find the value of $u$ when x = 1 (the bound of integration are given in terms of x: from 0 to 1, when substituting, we need to get the corresponding bounds in terms of $u$.

Comment: See [integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)

Comment: does this means every time when I substitute a variable to U, I have to find the new bounds of X ?

Comment: For definite integrals, yes, it is smart to do, because after integrating in terms of $u$, you might forget to change u back to the expression which we let u equal. And it simplifies matters.

Comment: If the case here is (4x+1)^1/2 dx from 0 to 2. I'll get the answer or 1/6(4x+1)^3/2. So my bound should be the original 0 to 2, or 1 to 9 ?

Comment: Not if you substitute back the expression (4x + 1) like you did. If we let u = 4x+1, then when we find the integral in terms of u, you can either use new bounds you suggest for evaluating the integral in terms of u, or we can "back substitute (4x+1) for u, and use the bounds of integration for x.  So with the answer you state, you use the orginal bounds as given for x.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in my original question if I did not use U for 2x+1, and with original bound 0 to 1. I seem to find a negative answer, not even close to 2/9. That's the thing I don't understand

Comment: Wwait. nevermind. I see my errors

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me all the help. I wish I can give you more point for all these helps =)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the antiderivative of $(2x+1)^{-3}$ is $-\frac14(2x+1)^{-2}$.

Also, there is a sign error when you plug in the lower limit $x=0$. (You have one minus sign from the antiderivative $F$ and another from the difference $F(1)-F(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using $u$-substitution with $u=2x+1$ so that $du=2dx$. Substitution yields $$\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3u^{-3}du=-\frac{1}{4}u^{-2}\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=3}=\frac{-1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{9}-1\right)=2/9.$$

Comment: Thanks for all the helps guy. but i dont understand how u guys change from x=0 to x=1, to x=1 to x=3

Comment: @user61618: Since we set $u=2x+1$, we plug in the lower bound ($x=0$) to get $u=2(0)+1=1$ and the upper bound ($x=1$) to get $u=2(1)+1=3$.

Comment: Will someone explain the downvote, please?

Comment: What's this property or formula comes from ? I don't think I've learned this from my teacher yet. Could you guys show me a website link regarding to this ?

Comment: See [this page on integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) for your questions. It's usually one of the earliest techniques taught for integration.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{(2x+1)^3} dx$$

Let $2x+1=y$, $2dx=dy$ and 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1}\rightarrow \int_1^{3}\\
\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{(2x+1)^3} dx&=\int_1^{3} \frac{1}{2y^3} dy\\
&=\left(\frac{-1}{4y^2}\right)_1^3\\
&=\vdots
\end{align}
You messed up the last step.

Comment: @julien. Must be careful during copy-pasting. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the helps guy. but i dont understand how u guys change from x=0 to x=1, to x=1 to x=3

Comment: @user61618, $2x+1=y$ so, when $x=0, y=2\times 0 + 1 = 1$, and similarly, when $x=1,y=3$.

Comment: What's this property or formula comes from ? I don't think I've learned this from my teacher yet. Could you guys show me a website link regarding to this ?